# JPA / Hibernate - LazyLoading OneToMany duplicando registros

Tags: java, java-ee, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Bom, tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
public class FinCxaTransacaoGrupo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Type(type="pg-uuid")
    @Column(name="id_fin_cxa_transacao_grupo")
    private UUID idFinCxaTransacaoGrupo;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_fin_cxa_transacao_destino")
    private FinCxaTransacao finCxaTransacaoDestino;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_fin_cxa_transacao_origem")
    private FinCxaTransacao finCxaTransacaoOrigem;

}

public class FinCxaTransacao {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    @Column(name = "id_fin_cxa_transacao")
    private UUID idFinCxaTransacao;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "finCxaTransacao")
    private List<FinCxaPlanoLcto> finCxaPlanoLctos = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="finCxaTransacaoDestino")
    private List<FinCxaTransacaoGrupo> finCxaTransacaoGruposDestino = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="finCxaTransacaoOrigem")
    private List<FinCxaTransacaoGrupo> finCxaTransacaoGruposOrigem = new ArrayList<>();

}

public class FinCxaPlanoLcto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Type(type="pg-uuid")
    @Column(name="id_fin_cxa_plano_lcto")
    private UUID idFinCxaPlanoLcto;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_fin_cxa_transacao")
    private FinCxaTransacao finCxaTransacao;

}
```

Query executada para encontrar o Grupo:

```
public FinCxaTransacaoGrupo buscarFinCxaTransacaoGrupoEstorno(UUID idFinCxaTransacao) {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<FinCxaTransacaoGrupo> query = cb.createQuery(FinCxaTransacaoGrupo.class);
    Root<FinCxaTransacaoGrupo> finCxaTransacaoGrupo = query.from(FinCxaTransacaoGrupo.class);
    query.where(cb.or(cb.equal(finCxaTransacaoGrupo.get(FinCxaTransacaoGrupo_.finCxaTransacaoDestino).get(
            FinCxaTransacao_.idFinCxaTransacao), idFinCxaTransacao),
            cb.equal(finCxaTransacaoGrupo.get(FinCxaTransacaoGrupo_.finCxaTransacaoOrigem).get(
                    FinCxaTransacao_.idFinCxaTransacao), idFinCxaTransacao)));

    query.distinct(true);

    query.select(finCxaTransacaoGrupo).distinct(true);
    return em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
}
```

A tabela FinCxaTransacaoGrupo contém um registro.
A tabela FinCxaTransacao contém um registro para finCxaTransacaoDestino e finCxaTransacaoOrigem;

a tabela FinCxaPlanoLcto contém dois registro para finCxaTransacaoDestino e um registro para finCxaTransacaoOrigem;

Lembrando que na estrutura, o FinCxaPlanoLcto é LazyLoading... Ao buscar finCxaTransacaoDestino.getFinCxaPlanoLctos() essa lista retorna com registros duplicados, ou seja, o retorno são 4 itens e no banco de dados contém apenas dois, sendo uma duplicação para cada registro.

Porém no objeto finCxaTransacaoOrigem.getFinCxaPlanoLctos() que contém apenas um registro no banco, essa lista retorna apenas um registro, sem duplicações...

Pesquisei diversos exemplos onde o pessoal soluciona usando Set ao invés de List para a relação OneToMany, isso soluciona o meu problema, mas em outras situações não me permite inserir valores duplicados quando necessário.

Gostaria de saber porque o JPA está duplicando os registros e se existe alguma solução?

Comment: Cara vou te dar uma sugestão de `debug`, adiciona um arquivo `properties` do `log4j` na pasta `resources` do seu projeto e ativa o log de `sql` full do `Hibernate`, para ver se esta executando dois `inserts`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução que fiz para o meu problema foi converter a lista para um Set<> e depois adicionar novamente para a List e retorna-la. Sim  e considero uma gambiarra, assim que possível vou realizar a sugestão repassada e usar o log4j.

Grato.

Set finCxaPlanoLctos = new HashSet<>(finCxaTransacaoGrupoReturn.getFinCxaTransacaoDestino().getFinCxaPlanoLctos());
            finCxaTransacaoGrupoReturn.getFinCxaTransacaoDestino().getFinCxaPlanoLctos().clear();
            finCxaTransacaoGrupoReturn.getFinCxaTransacaoDestino().getFinCxaPlanoLctos().addAll(finCxaPlanoLctos);